# Is there a way to make separate files for components such as logic, html and CSS in ReactJS like Angular?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

I am completely new to ReactJS. I have previously worked in Angular for my office work and I liked the way it is so much organised as the logic files (component.ts or module.ts, scss and HTML) files are separate. I have been started to watch a react tutorial on youtube and saw they styling, logic and HTML are inside the same file. I know that that is not actually HTML. But is there a proper way to keep those codes in separate files like angular?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working:https://therichpost.com/how-to-include-html-file-in-angular-12-component/

Answer (score 4):

It's quite possible, you just need to set up your environment to support it.

Let's say you want to separate things as much as possible - you want the functions associated with a component to be in one file, the JSX associated with the component in another, and the CSS in another. To start with, you'll need a module bundler like Webpack, which your React installation may already have integrated. A module bundler allows you to take multiple separate files in a project and compiles them together into a single (or multiple, if you wish) file for production.

To bundle all CSS into a single file with Webpack, see [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) and use the option [`chunks: "all"`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#extracting-all-css-in-a-single-file) in your Webpack config. Then you can import CSS files in your JavaScript. For example:

```
// componentA.jsx
import './styleA.css';
// other componentA JS code...
```

```
// componentB.jsx
import './styleB.css';
// other componentB JS code...
```

can be used to write your styles for componentA and componentB in separate files, import them via the JS, and Webpack will transform it into a single usable CSS file for production.

If you don't want Webpack to merge everything into a single CSS file, that's easy to manage too - that's what the plugin does by default.

You can [easily integrate CSS preprocessors](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) like SCSS if you want.

In the component's JavaScript, you're free to import functions from other files. eg:

```
// ComponentA.jsx
import './styleA.css';
import { makeApiCall } from './makeApiCall.js';

export const ComponentA = (props) => {
  const [callMade, setCallMade] = useState(false);
  const handler = () => makeApiCall().then(() => setCallMade(true));
  return (
    <button onClick={handler}>{callMade}</button>
  );
};
```

allowing you to separate out the JavaScript logic, and the JavaScript logic from the component's JSX as much as desired.

A word of caution, though. Putting related functions in separate files can increase boilerplate to an undesirable level. For example, if you have multiple states, and you'd want a few functions to all have access to those multiple states and be able to set them, you'd have to pass *all* those values to the functions when calling them. Eg

```
const [stateVal1, setStateVal1] = useState(
const [stateVal2, setStateVal2] = useState(
```

If you had two functions that needed both of these states and their setters, and the functions are in separate files, you'd need something like

```
importedFn1(stateVal1, setStateVal1, stateVal2, setStateVal2);
importedFn2(stateVal1, setStateVal1, stateVal2, setStateVal2);
```

Kind of ugly. I'd recommend:

- Abstracting into separate files functionality that *doesn't have to do with React* - such as API calls. For React code, like state and state setters, having those written out in the component itself could well be easier. (so you can do things like `const handler = () => makeApiCall().then(() => setCallMade(true));` as shown above)
- If the component gets too long to be reasonably understood as a whole easily, consider creating sub-components in separate files rather than trying to figure out a way to put everything into a single component manageably.